# Javascript attempt to keep sidebar at 100vh at all times

Tags: javascript, dom

Working on a project requiring old-school CSS support and want to keep `<aside>` filling up the page by remaining the same height as the `<article>` element's box (It may be between a header and footer, in which case it would not extend past them.)

```
<article id="article">
...
<aside id="sidebar">
```

Here's my attempt at dynamically setting the height. It doesn't seem to work.

```
<script>                                                                  
function sidebarHeight() {                                                
sidebar=window.document.getElementById('sidebar')                         
article=window.document.getElementById('article')                         
sidebar.style.height=article.style.height;                                
console.log('article.style.height: ' + article.style.height);             
}
window.onresize=sidebarHeight;                                            
</script>
```

This doesn't work because `article.style.height` always has the value `""` instead of the current height. How can I keep the sidebar stretched vertically in sync with the article height?

By the way, can someone explain why the only way to get at properties like height, or at least color, which I know works, requires a call to `getElementById()`? If I use the more logical-sounding `getElementsByTagName('article')` I get access to a much more limited set of properties.

Comment: Why are you required to use "old-school CSS"? What are your **specific** requirements? If you need to support IE11, then say so - or if you need to support some older or obscure rendering engine then please clarify.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` you mean?  I think you put the `s` in the wrong place

Comment: where and how is `sidebarHeight` invoked?

Comment: @Dai, I am targeting from Android 4 on up, so inexpensive cell phones in low-bandwidth conditions can view the web pages. I have updated to show when the code is invoked, which is window.onresize. And mysteriously, the function has an "s" in an odd place: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName.

Comment: `.style.height` only returns height explicitly set in the html markup, you'll need to get the calculated height `.offsetHeight`

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) rather than the [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) returned by `getElementById` or `querySelectorAll`. `HTMLCollection`s are live references to the DOM and change as you make changes making them trickier to work with.

Comment: @pilchard Thanks, that got me halfway there. However the code sidebar.style.height=article.offsetHeight appears to do nothing. In fact, if I do something like sidebar.style.height='10px' in the console nothing happens either. P.S. Thanks for explaining HTMLCollection. TIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the calculated height `onresize` you need to use `.offsetHeight` and you need to add a unit to the returned value.

```
sidebar.style.height = `${article.offsetHeight}px`;
```

also, your DOM queries should just be called on `document`

```
sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar')                         
article = document.getElementById('article')
```

```css
article {
  float: left;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 75vw;
  background-color: gray;
}

aside {
  float: right;
  width: 20vw;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<article id="article"></article>
<aside id="sidebar"></aside>

<script>                                                                  
function sidebarHeight() {                                                
sidebar= document.getElementById('sidebar')                         
article= document.getElementById('article')                         
sidebar.style.height= `${article.offsetHeight}px`;         
}
window.onresize=sidebarHeight;                                            
</script>
```

Comment: Damnit, this is like Christmas in... December and I don't know a better way to thank you. Do have a favorite cause or is there some way to thank you more materially since I'm not even supposed to be thanking you in this comment? Patreon or something? No contact info in your profile and I feel bad. This is going into an open source CMS to be named Metabuzz so you're helping more people than just me. It's part of a free speech project & I'm terribly grateful.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped.